# Como eu passo duas váriaveis para o parâmetro onclick?

Tags: php, html

se eu coloco só uma variável dá certo,mas eu preciso também passar $cidade para o onclick, mas eu não sei como concatenar da forma correta. 
(função deleteVaga)

```
 while($registros = $querySelect->fetch_assoc()){
       $id = $registros['id'];
       $cidade = $registros['cidade'];
       $empresa = $registros['empresa'];
       $setor = $registros['setor'];
       $remuneracao = $registros['remuneracao'];
       $beneficios = $registros['beneficios'];
       $nivel_estagio = $registros['nivel_estagio'];
       $vinculo = $registros['vinculo'];
       $processo_sel = $registros['processo_seletivo'];
       $contato = $registros['contato'];   

      echo '<button onclick="deleteVaga('.$id.'.','.'.$cidade.')"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" style="font-size:36px;color:#f00;"></i></button>';
       echo "</tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Na dúvida não concatene, interpole (ou formate) a *string*:

```
echo sprintf('<button onclick="deleteVaga(%d, \'%s\')">...</button>', $id, $cidade);
```

Interpolando poderia ficar:

```
echo "<button onclick='deleteVaga({$id}, \"{$cidade}\")'>...</button>";
```

A sintaxe que você usou, `'.$id.'.','.'.$cidade.'`, nem faz sentido. Você concatena uma *string* com `$id`, concatena um caractere ponto, depois vem uma vírgula que está sobrando no código, depois mais um caractere ponto, para então concatenar com `$cidade`, que teria seu valor fora das aspas no JS, gerando erro de sintaxe.

Se ainda restou dúvidas, analise o HTML gerado e veja se condiz com o que você queria gerar.

Comment: Eu preciso que o ajax em outro arquivo receba esses dois parâmetros

Comment: mas continua dando erro

Comment: eu estou usando aspas simples para abrir o echo e aspas duplas para abrir as funções

Comment: Analisou o HTML gerado como sugerido? O que concluiu?

Comment: sim,ele gera os resultados na tabela, mas não deleta

Comment: function deleteVaga(deleteid,cidade){
        var conf = confirm('Quer mesmo excluir essa vaga?');
        if(conf==true){
          $.ajax({
          url: "banco_de_dados/delete.php",
          type: "post",
          data: {deleteid: deleteid, cidade: cidade},
          success: function(data, status){
            viewVagas();
          }
        });
      }
    }

Comment: desculpa o código, saiu como texto comum

Comment: Se o HTML gerado está correto e a função é chamada corretamente, sua pergunta foi respondida. Se o jQuery também está com problemas, sugiro abrir outra pergunta.